# Complicated derivative involve to get maximum likelihood estimator

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, statistical-inference, bayesian

> A random variable $X$ follows the distribution given below:
> $$\left(X=x|\gamma\right)= \frac{{2 \choose x}\gamma^x\left(1-\gamma\right)^{2-x}}{1-\left(1-\gamma\right)^2}, \; x= \{1,2\}$$
> A sample of $\textbf{n}$ i.i.d random varaibles observed. Estimate the parameter $\gamma$.

log likelihood function,
$$
\begin{align*}
\ln L &=\frac{1}{1-\left(1-\gamma\right)^2}\left( \sum_{i=1}^n\ln{2 \choose x_i}+\sum_{i=1}^nx_i\ln\gamma+\sum_{i=1}^n(2-x_i)\ln\left(1-\gamma\right)\right)
\end{align*}
$$
The expression is too much ugly. How to differentiate it with respect to $\gamma$? And does the information $x=\{1,2\}$ have some significance?

Comment: There are only two possibilities, so this is essentially just a Bernoulli distribution. You can simplifiy this formula a lot by just saying $P(X=2)=p$, $P(x=1)=1-p$. The $\gamma$ which maxmises the likelihood is the $\gamma$ corresponding to the $p$ which maximises the likelihood.

Comment: Where is this from?

Comment: I didn't understand you completely. Like how considering $P(X=2)=p,P(X=1)=1-p$, simplify my formula because I can't observe the sample and infer this like $p.p.(1-p)\cdots$? Because finally I need to differentiate the likelihood wrt $\gamma$, isn't it? As I can't plug-in values for $\gamma$ with random values. @ZoeAllen Can you expand your comment or redirect me any example/resource?

Comment: This is my homework problem @Snoop. We didn't cover to get MLE for discrete case greatly. That's why facing issue to do it by myself. Any hints will be appreciated also.

Comment: You can use linearity of the derivative to break this up, so you just need to be able to compute the derivative of $\frac{1}{1-(1-\gamma)^2}$, $\frac{\ln \gamma}{1-(1-\gamma)^2}$, and $\frac{\ln(1-\gamma)}{1-(1-\gamma)^2}$ with respect to $\gamma$.  Do you have trouble evaluating any of those derivatives individually?

Comment: I can derivative those terms. But I guess this not the best way to solve this problem. As ZoeAllen pointed, $x=\{1,2\}$ use be used to simplify the problem. And here I lost how to do that. @user6247850

Comment: Possibly that can be used to simplify some of the expressions, but it isn't necessary.  I would suspect that those sums can maybe be written in terms of the number of $x_i$s which are 1 and the number which are 2, e.g. using that $\ln \binom{2}{x_i} = 0$ when $x_i = 2$, but it's fine to just leave the sums as they are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\Pr[X = x \mid \gamma] = \begin{cases} 1 - \frac{\gamma}{2-\gamma}, & x = 1 \\ \frac{\gamma}{2-\gamma}, & x = 2. \end{cases} \tag{1}$$

So the original comment that $X$ is essentially Bernoulli distributed (specifically, $X - 1$ is Bernoulli) is correct, and the likelihood of $\gamma$ given a sample of size $n$ is straightforward to compute:

$$\mathcal L(\gamma \mid \boldsymbol x) = \left(1 - \frac{\gamma}{2-\gamma}\right)^{\sum \mathbb 1(x_i = 1)} \left(\frac{\gamma}{2-\gamma}\right)^{\sum \mathbb 1(x_i = 2)}. \tag{2}$$

For convenience, let us define the sufficient statistic $m = \sum \mathbb 1(x_i = 2)$, which simply counts the number of observations in our sample that have value $2$; then $n-m$ is the number of observations that have value $1$.  Also, let $p = \gamma/(2-\gamma)$, so the likelihood is expressible in terms of $m$:
$$\mathcal L(\gamma \mid m) = p^m (1-p)^{n-m}. \tag{3}$$
Now this should look much more familiar.  The critical point that maximizes $\mathcal L$ corresponds to the choice $\hat p = m/n$, and by invariance, it follows that $$\hat \gamma = \frac{2m}{m+n} \tag{4}$$ where again, $m$ is defined as above.  Alternatively we may express $(4)$ in terms of the sample total $s = \sum x_i$, since $s = m+n$:  $$\hat \gamma = 2 - \frac{2n}{s} = 2 - \frac{2n}{\sum x_i}. \tag{5}$$

Answer (score 1):

It seems that there is a mistake in your computatation of the log-likelihood: instead of dividing by $1-(1-\gamma)^2$, one should substract $\log (1-(1-\gamma)^2)$. The derivative is a rational fraction in $\gamma$ hence by multiplying by the common denominator, you are reduced to solve a quadratic equation.